# C# - How can I ensure a member is invoked without needing to call it and rely on the { get; }

Tags: c#, object-oriented, abstract-factory

I'm using reflection as a way of implementing a factory pattern:

```
        Type type = GetProviderType(vendor);
        ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(NameValueCollection) });
        ExternalSourceProvider vendorSourceProvider = (ExternalSourceProvider)constructorInfo.Invoke(new Object[] { requestData });
```

I can ensure that a member of the fabricated object is invoked by adding this code:

```
        _externalSiteId = vendorSourceProvider.ExternalId;
        _app = vendorSourceProvider.App;
```

This is smelly - I shouldn't need to 'touch' the member to ensure it's invoked. Any ideas on how to ensure invocation of the member? The reason I want to invoke these members is that I need to 'bootstrap' the fabricated 'vendorSourceProvider' object (and touching the member allows me to do this in the {get} of the member). Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm trying to do without needlessly 'touching' the member?

Comment: What's smelly is that you *want to* invoke a getter without using the result.

Comment: Questions asking for assistance in explaining, writing or debugging code are off-topic here. Please ask this on Stack Overflow. Voting to close.

Comment: You're using reflection to invoke a constructor that could otherwise be invoked with `new`.  You already have a lot of smell; what significant difference will "touching your member" make? [insert Saturday Night Live joke here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating your overcomplifications.

If you want to bootstrap an object into a specific state, then **give it a method that accomplishes this**.

What you're doing is akin to using magic and quantum mechanics to sort a deck of cards.  Why not simply **sort the deck of cards** (`deck.sort()` or `deck.prepare()`)?